# Validate method for form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and i want it to validate with my method validateForm() made with jQuery:

```
function validateForm() {
var count = 0;

$("input[type='text']").each(function () {
    if ($(this).id == "AbdominalCircumferencetext") {
        if ($("#AbdominalCircumferencetext").val() == "" || ($("#AbdominalCircumferenceradio").val().length == 0)) {
            ($("#AbdominalCircumferencetext").css("border", "2px solid red"));
            ($("#AbdominalCircumferenceradio").css("border", "2px solid red"));
            count++;
        }
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).css("border", "2px solid red");

        count++;
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("border", "");
    }

});

var checkboxGroupNames = [];

$(':radio').each(function () {
    var nameOfCheckBoxGroup = $(this).attr('name');
    var nameExistInList = jQuery.inArray(nameOfCheckBoxGroup, checkboxGroupNames);
    if (nameExistInList < 0) {
        checkboxGroupNames.push(nameOfCheckBoxGroup);
    }
});

   var counter = 0;
var counts = 0;
$.each(checkboxGroupNames, function () {
    if ( $("input[name='" + checkboxGroupNames[counter] + "']:checked").length === 0) {
        $("#" + checkboxGroupNames[counter] + "radio").css("border", "2px solid red");
        counts++;
    } 
    else {
        $("#" + checkboxGroupNames[counter] + "radio").css("border", "");
    }
    counter++;





});
if (counts == 0 && count == 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    alert("Du måste fylla i alla rutorna samt välja något alternativ av radioknapparna!");
    return false;
}
```

}

The problem is that i want to make a count for every textfield or radiobutton that doesn't have a value. So each time the border sets to red it doesn't have a value and in that case i want to do a count as in the code. Then after the code have gone through all textboxes and radiobuttons i want to se if any of them failed. But i cant do the count as in the end of my code. It says that it will always be true. if there a better way to do this? or am i doing it the right way but i have the wrong syntax or something?

Comment: Not an answer to you question but why not use something like http://formvalidator.net/

Comment: i forgott to mention that the form is dynamiclly created so i can't set value for every input in the form. I think i have to go through every input in a loop.

Comment: so you're saying you are always getting true? are the borders added to the elements?

Comment: if (counts == 0 && count == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Du måste fylla i alla rutorna samt välja något alternativ av radioknapparna!");
        return false;
    }

This code in the end of the code above will always return true is what visual studio tells me :P

Comment: yes I've seen your code before, what exactly is the problem? what behavior are you experiencing?

Comment: Did you debug your code? try to console.log(count)

Comment: the problem is that i want to return true if all inputs have a input value and false otherwise. But with the last method i can't do that fo some reason. So what i want is a method that adds to a count each time one of the inputs have inputvalue 0.

Comment: what do you mean you 'can't do that'? what happens when you submit the form with empty values? are the borders being applied? do as @Dh.. suggested and put console.log(count) before your last if

Comment: You should not have more than one element with the same id. Use `data-` attributes to specify which inputs you want to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a bit "all over the place". If you have a function containing three variables named "count", "counter" and "counts" you should feel that you're getting in the wrong direction :)

If I have understood your code correctly all you want to do is to check that no input of type text is left empty and that all radio button options is checked. If so is the case I would write somehting like this http://jsbin.com/iluquz/4/edit

```
function validateForm() {

var isMissingAnswer = false,
  radioButtons = [];

// Go through inputs in form
$('input:not([type="submit"])').each(function() {

    // Collect radio button names
    if( this.type == 'radio' ) {
      if( $.inArray(this.name, radioButtons) == -1 ) {
        radioButtons.push(this.name);
      }
    }

    // Check if answer is given
    else {
      if( this.value == '' ) {
        $(this).css('border', 'red solid 2px');
        isMissingAnswer = true;
      } else {
        $(this).css('border', '');
      }            
    }        
});

// Go through radio buttons and make sure they're checked
$.each(radioButtons, function(i, name) {
    var $radioButtons = $('input[name="'+name+'"]');
    if( $radioButtons.filter(':checked').length == 0 ) {
      $radioButtons.parent().css('border', 'red solid 2px');
      isMissingAnswer = true;
    } else {
      $radioButtons.parent().css('border', '');
    }
});

if( isMissingAnswer ) {
    alert("Du måste fylla i alla rutorna samt välja något alternativ av radioknapparna!");
    return false;
} else {
    alert('Allt gick bra :)');
    return true;
}

}
```